# passing php result to html infowindow

Tags: php, html

Hello everyone hope all are doing good,
This is my first post and I am very new to php and html.I have got to work on GIS using Gmap i have some code where in php code I am accesing db and retriving result $rows those row elements I want to display in infowindow dropdown input,infowindow apeares when click on map please suggest methods to do this. if I get some examples of this kind that will be great..

```
    <?php 
$serverName = "localhost\SQLEXPRESS"; $connectionInfo = array  
( "Database"=>"master", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"sa");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo );
if( $conn === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$sql = "SELECT Group_ID FROM Test where configured =1";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) { //Here in $ row i get result which i want to display as dropdown in below html
    /// echo $row['Group_ID']."<br />";
}
sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
?>
```

Below is infowindow code where I want to add dropdown with result of php
 inplace of options I am hard coding here now

```
    $(map).click( function(event) {
    $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', {'position': event.latLng, 'draggable':     
    true, 'bounds': false}, function(map, marker) {
$('#dialog').append('<form id="dialog'+marker.__gm_id+'" method="get" action="/" style="display:none;"><p><label for="country">Country</label><input id="country'+marker.__gm_id+'" class="txt" name="country" value=""/></p><p><label for="state">State</label><input id="state'+marker.__gm_id+'" class="txt" name="state" value=""/></p><p><label for="address">Address</label><input id="address'+marker.__gm_id+'" class="txt" name="address" value=""/></p><p><label for="Group">Group</label><select><option value="G4">Group4</option><option value="G1">Group1</option><option value="G2">Group2</option><option value="G3">Group3</option></select></p><p><label for="test">Comment</label>'<?php echo ($row); ?>'</p></form>')};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery's [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) function:

```
$.get('php_source', function(data) {
    //data variable holds values returned by php script
    //parse and append data to #dialog
});
```